# Repeatedly calling a hotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I've tried to implement a t flip flop(I think this is what it's called) into my program but am having some issues with it. The idea is to have the program start and stop while using the same hotkey. This is what I have so far.

```
looping := false
pass = 0
max = 2

^r::
   pass++
   looping := true
   while(looping = true AND pass < max)
   {
      Send, stack overflow, save me!
   }

   looping := false
   pass = 0
return
```

When I run the program and hit the hotkey the while loop starts. However, when I attempt to break the loop by pressing ^r I get no response and the program keeps looping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are referring to a "toggle" script. I am not what sure you are trying to achieve exactly, but the key is using a logical not: `looping := !true`. More about it [here](http://maul-esel.github.io/ahkbook/en/toggle-autofire.html).

```
looping := false
pass = 0
max = 2

^r::
   pass++
   looping := !true
   while (looping & pass < max)
   {
      Send, stack overflow, save me!
   }
   pass = 0
return
```

There's a lot of resources for this, here are a few:
https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=11952
http://maul-esel.github.io/ahkbook/en/toggle-autofire.html
https://www.reddit.com/r/AutoHotkey/comments/6wqgbu/how_do_i_toggle_hold_down_a_key/dmad0xx